# Use multiple softmax in transformers output layer and calculate loss

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, softmax, transformer-model, seq2seq

Can I use multiple softmax in the last output layer in transformers? If so, how can I calculate loss from that. I am working in pytorch.

And I am asking because my data is a sequence of tuples where, the elements have different dimensions. Like,

```
[(2,1), (3,1), (3,1), (2,1), (2,1), (3,1), (3,0), (4,1)]
```

The first element of tuples has a vocab of `5` and the second element of tuples has a vocab of `2`.